# MySQL: Get count of data in comma separated column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores data like:

```
userid    books
ym0001    dictionary,textbooks,notebooks
ym0002    textbooks,dictionary
```

I want to count number of times each book occurs. I want my result to be in this format.

```
books       Counts
dictionary  2
notebooks   1
textbooks   2
```

This is mysql. Please help

Comment: None of the answers provided solve my problem hence my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach builds a result of 1000 integers, then uses those integers (n) to locate segments within the comma seperated string, and for each segment it creates a new row so that the derived table looks like this:

> ```
> userid | book      
> :----- | :---------
> ym0001 | dictionary
> ym0002 | textbooks 
> ym0001 | textbooks 
> ym0002 | dictionary
> ym0001 | notebooks
> ```

Once that exists it is a simple matter of grouping by book to arrive at the counts.

> ```
> select
>     book, count(*) Counts
> from (
>     select
>            t.userid
>          , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.books, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) book
>     from (
>         select @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS n
>         from
>         (
>            select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
>            union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 
>            union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
>         ) a
>         cross join (
>            select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
>            union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 
>            union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
>         ) b
>         cross join  (
>            select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
>            union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 
>            union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
>         ) c
>         cross join (select @rownum:=0) r
>         ) numbers
>     inner join mytable t
>       on CHAR_LENGTH(t.books)
>         -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(t.books, ',', '')) >= numbers.n-1
>     ) d
> group by
>     book
> order by
>     book
> ```
>
> ```
> book       | Counts
> :--------- | -----:
> dictionary |      2
> notebooks  |      1
> textbooks  |      2
> ```

1. If you already have a table of numbers, use that instead.
2. the cross joins of a b and c dynamically produce 1000 rows, if you need more add further cross joins similar to c. i.e. **the number of numbers should exceed the maximum length of your comma seperated data**

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fcd1daad016de7b81c6d32d40480682c)*

Comment: You are a life saver. This worked like charm. Thank you

Comment: In truth it isn't good practice to store data in that comma sepersted fashion but I'm pleased your immediate problem is solved.

Comment: read why here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad